# best way to programatically edit a sql query?

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have a dictionary of sql queries, where the key is the name of a view, and the value is the query like so:

```
SELECT
  artists.first_name,
  artists.last_name,
  artist_sales.sales
FROM database.artists
JOIN (
    SELECT artist_id, SUM(sales_price) AS sales
    FROM database.sales
    GROUP BY artist_id
  ) AS artist_sales
  ON artists.id = artist_sales.artist_id;
```

What I would like to do is programatically replace the table name, so that it can become something like `catalog.database.artists` and `catalog.database.sales`. So whatever function I have would I think use regex to find what is after the `FROM` clause and edit the table name to include the `catalog` before the name of the database. Any thoughts for this?

Comment: Put something like `<database>` in the SQL. Then use `.replace('<database>', database_name)` to substitute that.

Comment: Why do you need to specify the database name in the queries? When you connect to the server you normally set a default database. So if you want to use the DB dynamically, do it when connecting, and leave the SQL alone.

Comment: Careful here. SQL the language (sheaf of languages, with different dialects for different server makes and models) is notoriously hard to parse flawlessly. The tech you propose cannot be a module to develop, test, and then forget about. You'll have regressions when adding new queries.

Comment: Based on the question title alone, I'd suggest SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fragile regular expressions or direct string replacements, you can use a SQL parser such as [`sqlglot`](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) to make updates to the query when your desired conditions are met:

```py
import sqlglot # pip3 install sqlglot

def update_query(ast, find_tbl, replace_tbl):
   if isinstance(ast, (sqlglot.expressions.From, sqlglot.expressions.Join)) and \
        isinstance(ast.this, sqlglot.expressions.Table): # check if expression is a `from` or `join` and its child value is a `table` expression
      if all((t if isinstance(t:=getattr(ast.this, a), str) else t.sql()) in b \
        for a, b in find_tbl.items()): # if the table meets the find criteria...
          for a, b in replace_tbl.items():
              ast.this.args[a] = b # ... run replacements
          return
   for i in getattr(ast, 'args', {}).values(): #recurse over the expression's children, in place
      if isinstance(i, list):
         for j in i: update_query(j, find_tbl, replace_tbl)
      else:
         update_query(i, find_tbl, replace_tbl)

d = {'view':'''SELECT
  artists.first_name,
  artists.last_name,
  artist_sales.sales
FROM database.artists
JOIN (
    SELECT artist_id, SUM(sales_price) AS sales
    FROM database.sales
    GROUP BY artist_id
  ) AS artist_sales
  ON artists.id = artist_sales.artist_id;'''} # your dictionary
 
for view, query in d.items():
   ast = sqlglot.parse_one(query) # convert string query to `sqlglot` AST object
   update_query(ast, {'this':['artists', 'sales'], 'db':['database']}, 
      {'catalog':'catalog'}) # run update in place
   d[view] = ast.sql(pretty = True) # replace old query with updated AST object

print(d['view'])
```

Output:

```py
"""
SELECT
  artists.first_name,
  artists.last_name,
  artist_sales.sales
FROM catalog.database.artists
JOIN (
  SELECT
    artist_id,
    SUM(sales_price) AS sales
  FROM catalog.database.sales
  GROUP BY
    artist_id
) AS artist_sales
  ON artists.id = artist_sales.artist_id
"""
```

Explanation of `update_query`'s parameters `find_tbl` and `replace_tbl`:

`find_tbl`: a dictionary containing the target expression type and the values
(in a list) that a potential expression much match

Potential dictionary key names for target expressions:

- `"this"`: the base table name itself, i.e

  ```
  database.articles
  ```
- `"db"`: the database name, i.e

  ```
  database.articles
  ```
- `"catalog"`: the catalog name i.e

  ```
  catalog.database.articles
  ```

`replace_tbl`: a dictionary containing the replacement values (as a string) for a matched table expression:

Potential dictionary key names for target expression updates:

- `"this"`: the base table name itself, i.e

  ```
  database.articles
  ```
- `"db"`: the database name, i.e

  ```
  database.articles
  ```
- `"catalog"`: the catalog name i.e

  ```
  catalog.database.articles
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use fstrings:

depending on how you populate the dictionary, you might need to wrap it in a looping mechanism, but the essence of what you want I think is this:

```
table_name_1 = 'database.artists' 
table_name_2 = 'database.sales' 

query = f'''
SELECT
  artists.first_name,
  artists.last_name,
  artist_sales.sales
FROM {table_name_1}
JOIN (
    SELECT artist_id, SUM(sales_price) AS sales
    FROM {table_name_2}
    GROUP BY artist_id
  ) AS {table_name_2}
  ON {table_name_1}.id = {table_name_2}.artist_id;
  '''
```

this would generate a query string of:

> SELECT   artists.first_name,   artists.last_name,   artist_sales.sales
> FROM database.artists JOIN (
> SELECT artist_id, SUM(sales_price) AS sales
> FROM database.sales
> GROUP BY artist_id   ) AS database.sales   ON database.artists.id = database.sales.artist_id;

You could also use f-strings to define the table_name variables as well:

```
db = 'database_name'

table_name_1 = f'{db}.artists' 
table_name_2 = f'{db}.sales'
```

Those would give you variables with the values "database_name.artists" and "database_name.sales".

Not sure if its the full answer, but hopefully this answers the core of what youre stuck on.

Though if you have to do a find/replace after the dictionary is defined, then one approach could be iterate through the dictionary and use the string.split() function on each to split the query on 'FROM ' and then re-concatenate the list of strings generated from the split function with 'FROM catalog.' between the split values.

You could define the function to split the queries as 'split_queries' then use:

```
new_dict = dict((k, split_queries(v)) for k, v in original_dict.items())
```

This does assume that there is only one space after 'FROM' in each of the queries though. If that isn't necessarily true, they you'd want to replace your split_queries function with something leveraging regex, at which point, im not your guy  ¯\__(ツ)_/¯ sorry.

Hopefully at least some of this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `FROM` is a keyword in SQL and you'll presumably want to update every occurrence of it anyway, you could do a simple search and replace with regex, searching for and capturing a distinct phrase containing `from`, uppercase or not, and its trailing spaces and replacing that by itself and the name of the database you want to add.

For example:

```py
import re

# queries = {...your queries...}
expr = re.compile(r"(\bfrom[\t ]+)", re.IGNORECASE)
repl = r"\1catalog."

for key in queries: queries[key] = re.sub(expr, repl, queries[key])
```